# How to change locale in Symfony5 / PHPUnit before calling request?

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I need to change locale in my functional test:

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class TranslationControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {

        $client = static::createClient();

        $client->request('GET', '/translation.js');
        $client->getRequest()->setLocale('en');

        $content = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
        $trans = json_decode(substr($content, strpos($content, "'{") + 1, strpos($content, "}'") - strpos($content, "'{")), true);

        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertSame($trans['test.case'], 'en');

    }
}
```

Seems that $client->getRequest()->setLocale('en'); not working properly. What is the correct way?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it did not work for symfony 6.3 and also the link is now 404

Answer (score 1):

You have to "save" your session like this :

```
    $container = static::getContainer();
    /** @var SessionInterface $session */
    $session = $container->get('session');
    $session->set('_locale', 'de');
    $session->save();
    dump($session->get('_locale')); //de

    $session->set('_locale', 'en');
    $session->save();
    dump($session->get('_locale')); //en
```

From the source code :

> Force the session to be saved and closed.
> This method is generally not required for real sessions as the session will be automatically saved at the end of code execution.

SessionInterface source code : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.0/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/SessionInterface.php

Common usage : https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for this also for quite some time. I now found out, that it can be derived from https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html:

```
class MyTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $session = self::$container->get(SessionInterface::class);
        $session->set('_locale', 'de');

        $client->request('GET', '/dashboard');
        // The resulting page is in German
        ....
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is defined behavior, since changing the locale twice in a test behaves a bit strange:

```
class MyTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testIndex()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $session = self::$container->get(SessionInterface::class);
        $session->set('_locale', 'de');

        $client->request('GET', '/dashboard');
        // The resulting page is in English (my default locale)
        ....

        $session->set('_locale', 'nl');

        $client->request('GET', '/dashboard');
        // The resulting page is in German
        ....
    }
}
```